# Open iMessage composer after clicking app's notification banner?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I'm looking for a way to set up an iMessage after a user clicks my app's notification. Is there any way to do it directly, or would the notification have to open my app and then open MFMessageComposeVC? If I can only do the latter, how can I distinguish the user opening my app from a notification vs from clicking the icon? Could I pass information into my app, such as who to send the message to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there any way to do it directly, or would the notification have to open my app and then open MFMessageComposeVC?**

No, it will have to open your app first which in term will open MFMessageComposerVC.

**If I can only do the latter, how can I distinguish the user opening my app from a notification vs from clicking the icon?**

Yes, if the user opens the app from the notification, the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification` will be executed. If the user opens in the traditional way, the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will be executed, the `launchOptions` dictionary will contain your notification info.

**Could I pass information into my app, such as who to send the message to?**

Yes, you can pass information to your app through Push Notifications.

---

For further information, you you can refer to [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1),which even though is for iOS 6, it explains how Notification work and is a good starting point for you.